# Install Fedora from Fedora Live USB?

Tags: fedora, system-installation, live-usb

I've got a Windows 10 laptop that is successfully running Fedora 27 via Live USB.

I'd like to run the Fedora installer from that Fedora 27 Live USB to repartition the laptop HDD in order run Fedora and Windows from the HDD.

I don't see how to start the installer from my Live USB.  What am I missing?

Comment: When you boot into live USB and see the very first text menu, do you see "install" and "run live" options? If you don't you may be running a wrong image. What image file have you burnt onto the USB? I just went through the same process with no issues a couple days ago.

Comment: No text menus.  GUI password prompts for the encrypted filesystem and then user login.

Comment: Did you read Fedora installation guides? They should point you in the right direction. When I boot from live, I first see the menu similar to this (but not exactly, this is an older version) https://media.if-not-true-then-false.com/2014/12/01-fedora-21-grub.png